# Generate promises until rejected

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I have some code that returns a document from an API based on it's index, and I would like to progressively iterate over the API. I do not know how many elements the API will have, which is why I'd like to fetch data until one of the promises is rejected. Ideally this would be done using a generator to pass in values, but I don't know how I would make the following passage work

```
someapifunc() // Returns a promise

function* apifuncs() {
   var index = yield 1;
   index++;
   yield someapifunc(index - 1);
}

let calls = apifuncs();
apifuncs.next().value.then() // Works
apifuncs.next().value.then() // This won't because index and everything is out of the current scope
```

Comment: What do you need as the final result? do you need the intermediate results?

Answer (score 1):

This may be close to what you want, however, the last value "generated" will be a rejected promise

```
function* apifuncs() {
    var index = 1;
    var ok = true;
    var p;
    while(ok) {
        p = someapifunc(index);
        p.catch(() => ok = false);
        yield p;
        index += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting at index 100, if the API call doesn't return an error, it prints the data and then calls one lower index. When the API call returns an error, "Done" is printed.

```
function callAPI(index) {
  someapifunc(index).then(
    function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      callAPI(++index);
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log('Done');
    }
  );
}
callAPI(1);
```

Comment: the original code seems to start at 1 and increment